# Having trouble getting discord bot to respond to commands

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am struggling with a discord bot command that I've been working on recently. I am trying to use randint in order to roll for different outcomes but the number stays the same when i use the variable

```
x = (random.randint(1,100))

@bot.command()
async def eightball(ctx):
await ctx.send(x)
if x == 1:
    await ctx.send ("Thats very lucky!:8ball")
else:
    if x in range(11,98):
        await ctx.send ("Shame on you! The :8ball: says.")
    else:
        if x == 100:
            await ctx.send ("That also happens to be very fortunate :8ball:")
        else:
            if x in range(2, 10):
                await ctx.send ("Closer and closer! the :8ball: gets!")
            else:
                if x == 99:
                    await ctx.send ("Oof, :8ball:")
                else:
                    if x == 1:
                        await ctx.send ("Wow, The :8ball: Is Impressed")`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your `x` be inside the command. In your code, you are only randomly generating `x` once. You need to do it everytime someone uses the command.

```py
@bot.command()
async def eightball(ctx):
    x = random.randint(1,100)

    if x == 1:
        msg = "Thats very lucky! :8ball:"
    elif x in range(2, 10):
        msg = "Closer and closer! the :8ball: gets!"
    elif x in range(11, 98):
        msg = "Shame on you! The :8ball: says."
    elif x == 99:
        msg = "Oof, :8ball:"
    elif x == 100:
        msg = "That also happens to be very fortunate :8ball:"
    else:
        # can add else here if you wanted to
        # but we can't geenerated a number that ends up here so pointless
        # leaving for demo purposes
        pass        
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

I've also simplified your logic a bit - rather than lots of indented if/else statements, we can use if/elif to check other conditions if the first one is true. This makes your code a bit neater and allows adding other conditions a lot easier. I've also ordered the statements in numerical order - makes it easier to read and parse the logic a bit better. Here's a tutorial on [conditonal statements (if/else/elif)](https://realpython.com/python-conditional-statements/). Here's another on ["scope"](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/). The latter might help understand your `x` problem.

Could also use [`pattern matching`](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-match-case-statement/) but that's relatively new so best to stick to `if/elif/else` for now.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answered your question - please mark the answer as the solution/the answer. Thanks!